# How row-editing works in extjs 4.2?

Tags: grid, extjs4.2

Trying to understand how the row-editing works. Here is the **[example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/example/grid/row-editing.html)** on Sencha website.

So I see that we can edit and save row elements, but can someone explain me step-by-step where the updated/saved columns get stored? And how can I access them?

Also the Sencha demo has the code for row-editing. Thanks much

Answer (score 4):

Any changes made using the `RowEditing` plugin are done directly to the model in the store of the grid that you are editing.  You can then do as you please with that store to save to the server or wherever else using `store.sync()`;

One common way to save data entered using a row editor is to add an `edit` listener to your `RowEditing` plugin config, and make your server call there:

```
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    autoCancel: false,
    listeners: {
        edit: function(editor, context, eOpts) {
            var record = e.record;
            //do your processing here, e.g.:
            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: 'myServer/saveRecord',
                params: { record: record }
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I have using this code for editing the data, but I didn't get the edited row's values before the ajax call. how do I get the edited data ?and how to send the edited data through ajax to server side script.

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this row

```
var record = e.record;
```

here event e not define in this function. so change it to eOpts.record to get that record

and

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
                            url: url,
                            params: { record :  Ext.encode( record) } ,
                            success: function(data) {
                                store.load();
                            },
                            failure : function(record, operation) {
                                store.rejectChanges();
                            }
                        });
```